# To return large number of records in json

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

In the code below I am getting the values in `datatable` and returning as `jsonconvert`, but the values are not returning. There are nearly 3000 records. If there are a few records it is returning.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetDescriptions() 
    {
        string strLocation = "1";
        MastersClient objProductName = new MastersClient();

        DataSet Product = objProductName.GetLocationProductMap(int.Parse(strLocation));

        DataTable customerTable = Product.Tables[0];
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = 86753090 };

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerTable).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `JSON.NET` instead of `JavaScriptSerializer`?

Comment: what error do you exactly have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Response is not too large. You could increase your response size in your configuration file (web.config):

```
<configuration>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>  
             <webServices>                                                   
                 <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="86753090" />                 
             </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Adjust the `maxJsonLength` to fit your needs, but have in mind that Responses that are too large result in longer waits for the users.

**Edit**: You might also need to add this key under appSettings:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="50000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help u...

```
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer()
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
```